# calculate packet send/receive time

Tags: vue.js, webrtc, load-balancing, ping

i am using vue.js for webrtc client. My system has multi servers so i need to pick one and connect. I am getting server list from my webservice. Everything is ok till here, i want user connect to best server so decided to make custom ping (its called rtt, i think).
to sum up my aim is send a udp packet to server(sendTime in long), then server receives this packet and now server sends my a packet(receiveTime in long) => this servers ping is receiveTime - sendTime

So i will do this for every server and choose best server.Is it posible to send and receive udp packet or anyone got better idea?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the simplest way would be to make a get request to every url, then do a [promise race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) on the requests, which one returns the fastest is the server you would use.

```js
const urls = ['https://www.google.com/', 'https://www.facebook.com/', 'https://www.twitter.com/', 'https://www.instagram.com/'];

const serverPromises = [];

urls.forEach((url) => {
  serverPromises.push(
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch(url, {
        mode: 'no-cors'
      }).then((response) => {
        if ([400, 500, 404].includes(response.status)) {
          return reject(null);
        }
        return resolve(url);
      })
    })
  );
});

Promise.race(serverPromises).then((url) => {
  if (url) {
    console.log('URL to use: ', url);
  }
});
```

Check it out, see if it suits your needs!
To me this seems to be the easiest, and quickest way, without any calculations, plus you get the result as soon as the first request resolves, this way you don't have to wait for every request to resolve.